# how to show data in bootstrap charts using c#?

Tags: jquery, c#-4.0

I have data like below . I need to show data based on class with total absentees and presentess.Can you give suggestion for this query.I'm using c#.net for this data getting. Finally i need to dispaly  data in bootstrap barchart

```
ClassID className    Presnt Absent
18      Nursery      20      0  
19      LKG          47      0      
20      UKG          15      0      
21      First Class  34       0
```

Comment: This question is too broad, and you should include some existing code or your question will be closed.

Comment: Actually i need to show images .But images are not accepting because am new user. Complete description only i have given above. I have a doubt as how to show that data in bootstrap bar chart